# Can not run start script on docker and rancher

Tags: docker, wso2, rancher, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to get wso2 is running on a docker on Rancher. I have created the following dockerfile:

```
FROM        wso2/wso2base:latest
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y  && \
    apt-get install default-jdk -y && \
    apt-get clean 

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
ENV PATH ${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
ENV CARBON_HOME /opt/wso2is
```

It is uploaded to github. I have a docker-compose.ym file with the following content:

```
version: '2'
services:
  wso2is:
    build: <github-url>/wsois
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
    - 9443:9443/tcp
    - 9763:9763/tcp
    labels:
      io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
    volumes:
     - /home/dockserver/stacks/inclouding/volume/wso2is:/opt/wso2is
```

The only remaining step to have the server working is to run the start script. If i run it accessing to the docker bash It starts perfectly:

```
docker exec -it "676d5bc5cf18" bash
/opt/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh start
```

I have tried to launch it in the dockerfile with CMD:

```
CMD /opt/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh start
```

or in the docker-compose:

```
command:
- /opt/wso2is/bin/wso2server.sh
- start
```

On both situations the docker stops and shows errors stating:

```
Need to restart service reconcile
Expected state running but got stopped
```

How can I get it running? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try checking dumb-init by Yelp https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use start command (./wso2server.sh start) at the end of the command, wso2server.sh file starts the server in the background and it is the end of the wso2server.sh script execution. You can do the following to overcome the issue.

1. Do not use the start command. Just execute wso2server.sh.
2. Use start command with wso2server.sh file and tail the wso2carbon.log as follows.

> tail -f /repository/logs/wso2carbon.log